# AngularJS - How to orderBy the value of an array-like object in an ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, sorting, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an object that looks like this:

```
{
    "03" : "Apple",
    "02" : "Banana",
    "01" : "Cranberry"
}
```

and it orders it by the keys (which makes sense) in my ng-repeat. This results in the labels being out of alphabetical order ("cranberry" being first). How do I make it so that it orders my repeater by the values (alphabetically)?

I can supply it in the order I want to the ng-repeat, but it sorts it by the key. If I could make it *not* do that, then that would also work.

Comment: Is there anything stops you from sorting the data in controller?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but i do know that supplying the object pre-sorted won't work, because JS engines are not obliged to maintain the order of properties in an object.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

To sort array in ngRepeat you can use [orderBy filter](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:orderBy) but it works only with arrays, so you should use array in ngRepeat.

It will be something like this in controller:

```
$scope.myData = [
    {
        key:    "01",
        value:  "Cranberry"
    },
    {
        key:    "02",
        value:  "Banana"
    },
    {
        key:    "03",
        value:  "Apple"
    }
];
```

and in html:

```
<div class="item" ng-repeat="item in myData|orderBy:'value'">{{item.value}}</div>
```

Comment: But if you realy want to use object in scope you can create a filter that convert an object into array.

Comment: There was no particular need to use an object so I used the method you suggested and it's working great. Thank you :)